# Web.Config uppercase to lowercase Redirection - Losing HTTPS schema

Tags: asp.net

I have the following rule to redirect an upper case URL to a lower case URL

But what I see is the HTTPS URL is getting redirected to HTTP URL. So, https://example.com/UPPERCASE is getting redirected to http://example.com/uppercase. I want the redirect to happen to https URL i..e, https://example.com/uppercase. Please suggest.

```
 <rule name="LowerCaseRule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="[A-Z]" ignoreCase="false" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{URL}}" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^.*/install" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^.*/media" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^.*/App_Plugins" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^.*/css" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^.*/scripts" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url attribute does not include the schema, you need to explicitly specify the schema in the redirect:

```
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{ToLower:{HTTP_HOST}}{ToLower:{REQUEST_URI}}" />
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Perfect. Can you please tick this as the answer?